# Sort alphabetically a list of results: with MongoDB or JavaScript client?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sorting, nosql

I'm having a deep discussion with a friend of mine; we have a collection containing documents with one field "Name", among other fields. We need to show these documents, sorted alphabetically by that field, on the client.

We're using MongoDB to get those results and display a list. It's a simple find() query.

I think that the better approach is to use the sort method on the MongoDB query to get this list directly sorted alphabetically via `.sort({ Name: 1 })`, but he says to instead use the JavaScript client to sort the collection and then show it to the user.

What is the best solution and why? Thanks!

More info:

- For now, there's only 20 or 25 results.
- We're not paging.

Comment: If you're paging, you'll definitely want to do it inside MongoDB, otherwise you'll have to fetch all data from the database just to order and throw away the non visible results. Better to order and return just the results you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We're not paging (if that is the case, you're right). We have 20 or 25 results to show. The main fact is that my friend is stubborn about the fact that it must be in the JavaScript client the sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the scenario(s). *Usually*, it makes more sense to sort in the database, because it works with large and small collections, with complex filtering, pagination, has a consistent API, etc.

If the collection grows large, sorting on the client requires to read and transmit the entire collection, which is prohibitive, so large collections must be sorted server-side.

*However*, filtering on the client has the advantage that it's usually easier to implement and it's more dynamic, i.e. the user can select whether to sort ascending or descending, based on first name or last name and it can all happen without additional server requests / database calls. If this is a use case and the amount of data is small, the UX can be much better because of less time lag.

So, depending on your users needs, the perfect implementation might be one of the two or even a hybrid strategy that initially asks the server for a sorted result and, in case the result set is small enough, performs further sort operations on the client - which is also a perfectly diplomatic answer to your dispute :)

Comment: Good answer, clever and polite. Thanks for your reply. ;)